# Represent element of $SU(2)$ as a $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, quaternions, gaussian-integers

I am trying to write an element of $SU(2)$ with rational elements.  These are typically written in the form:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} x + iy & z + iw \\
-z + iw & x - iy \end{array}\right) \in SU(2, \mathbb{Q}) $$

And this should check out that this $2 \times 2$ matrix has determinant equal to $1$.  I've calculated:

$$ \det =  ||x+iy||^2 + ||z + iw||^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1$$

In order to find four numbers that when squared, sum to another square.

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} x + iy & z + iw \\
-z + iw & x - iy \end{array}\right]\in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[i]) \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc|cc}
x & -y & z & -w \\ 
y & x & w & z \\ \hline
-w & -w & x & y \\ 
w & -z & -y & x \end{array} \right] \in \text{GL}_4(\mathbb{Z}) $$

This can't be right.  This map is not a homomorphism.  In particular the determinants are different.  The second one is:

$$ \det = \big( x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4 \big) + (\dots)$$

and there are no cancellations.  This is slightly disconcerting.  I think this is becomes an attempt to write a "map" of some kind from:
$$ \mathbb{H} \to SU(2) \to SO(4) $$

We also know that the special unitary group is a $2:1$ cover of the $SO(3)$ lie group, so there must be a $3 \times 3$ matrix element as well.

---

I could try to write the thing using quaternions, I don't have the multiplications off hand:

$$ 1 \mapsto \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}
 \right]$$
The elements $i,j,k \in \mathbb{H}$ could also be represented a quaternions.

$$ 1 \mapsto \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 
\end{array}
 \right]$$
This is looking close to what I have.  Maybe it's no longer reasonable to expect the determinants to be the same?

Comment: make the $(3,1)$ entry in your first 4-by-4 determinant $-z$. Of course this hasn't the same determinant as your 2-by-2 matrix; its determinant is the square of that determinant.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown it's group isomorphism.  the determinant can change?  If the first representation is $V$ is the second representation $V \otimes V$.

Comment: So much doesn't make sense here. | The $2\times 2$ matrices you write out are, I'm guessing, elements of $SU(2,\Bbb Q[i])$, since presumably their entries are in $\Bbb Q[i]$, no? So don't write $SU(2,\Bbb Q)$. And don't abbreviate it $SU(2)$, since that's already shorthand for $SU(2,\Bbb C)$ (unless you're studying algebraic groups over general fields or something). Moreover, this is a subset of $GL_2(\Bbb Q[i])$, *not* of $GL_2(\Bbb Z[i])$ (since the entries of the matrices may not be in $\Bbb Z[i]$ at all). Similarly, you are writing down a $4\times4$ matrix in $GL_4(\Bbb Q)$ rather

Comment: than in $GL_4(\Bbb Z)$. | The map you wrote down from $2\times2$ to $4\times4$ matrices is a homomorphism, if you fix the typo Lord Shark points out. It failing to preserve the determinant would be of no consequence, because preserving determinants is nowhere in the definition of "group homomorphism" (the determinant only even makes sense for matrices anyway). But at least for elements in $SU(2,\Bbb Q[i])$ and $GL(4,\Bbb Q)$, your map *does* preserve determinants, as the determinant of the output factors as $(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)^2$, which is

Comment: just $1$ when the original $2\times2$ matrices started out with determinant $1$. Moreover, you can verify the output is indeed in $SO(4,\Bbb Q)$. | Do you also want a map $SU(2,\Bbb Q[i])\to SO(3,\Bbb Q)$? Really, your homomorphisms are just the restrictions of the usual ones for Lie groups over $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. And what "first representation" and "second representation" are you talking about in your comment?